# unable to set record in react usestate array from sqlite

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I am using sqlite for local storage in react native but when I tried to fetch record and set it into the useState , it doesn't update the state
here is the code

```
const SelectQuery=async()=>{
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('docToken')
let selectQuery = await ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM DoctorConversations where d_phone=?",[token]);
var rows = selectQuery.rows;
var temp = [];
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    temp.push(rows.item(i))
}
return temp;
}
```

This is how I am calling

```
SelectQuery().then(res=>res.map(item=>{
  setFlatListItem([...flatListItem,item])
}))
```

Comment: This looks fine, did you try to print the returned value by SelectQuery() ? Maybe it's empty

Comment: yes it prints all items in the console but couldn't update my flat list

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have:

```
const [flatListItem, setFlatListItem] = useState([]);
```

`setFlatListItem` changes internal state and schedules a rerender. `flatListItem` gets a new value only on the next render.

You need to use functional updates to modify the current internal state:

```
setFlatListItem(state => [...state, item])
```

If you want to replace the whole list, you do not need to map individual items:

```
SelectQuery().then(res=> setFlatListItem(res))
```

Note that `flatListItem` is a bad name in your case since it holds an array. You should probably rename it to just `[flatList, setFlatList]`.

Comment: yes, you got me and I have tried it. But, still unable to set it into the flat list

Comment: Do you want to have all your rows inside the `flatListItem` and replace all of them with the new ones from `SelectQuery`?